# GitHub Clone - how to prevent pull requests from going to the original repository?

Tags: git, github

I am going to clone a GitHub repo, and as per their instructions:

git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed.git my-proj

The additional steps I usually do after this, to prevent my updates from going back to that project, are:

```
rd .git /S/Q  (this removes the git links to the mgechev repo)
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin <my new repo address on github>
git push -u origin master
```

Are these steps necessary for me to prevent my subsequent branch creation, pull requests to my master etc from going to the original repo?

I don't want to inadvertently send request to the original repo, and I do it like this because I don't know any better to be honest. It's just that none of the clone/fork instructions in the Readme files of repos have these steps, and I had to go looking for them. So I don't know if I'm doing something unnecessary

Comment: If you're editing it, why not fork it and clone the fork?

Comment: Well that's not what the "How to Install" in the readme says:-) If I did that, I would save me some steps I guess. I want to use a different repo name though - could I still do that with the fork? But my question about my changes inadvertently going back to the original forked repo still stands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll lose all your history that way. Better to just change the url for the remote

```
git remote set-url origin <my new repo address on github>
```

Now the old url is no longer a part of the repository, so it's impossible to accidentally push there.